# Kendo grid sorting by date broken on filtered rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, momentjs

I have a kendo grid in my angular web app, whose source is dynamic(coming from a DB, so it's impossible to know the field types). To display a date field in the grid I use a moment.js format. The problem is that it changes the object's type to string, which brakes the grid sorting as it sorts by the string and not the date.
I have tried everything and it frustrates me greatly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: got some code or fiddle?

Comment: I'll be at work only after the weekend :|
Any ideas on how to have a date object and still display a formatted one?

Answer (score 0):

Just found another bug with the grid. Guess I'm switching to ng-table.